# Spree Can't add new preference with rails 7 app from a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I customize spree address auto complete gem to make it work with my rails 7 app. It was outdated.
this gem needs to add a new preference to app configuration

module Spree::AppConfigurationDecorator def self.prepended(base) base.preference :google_maps_api_key, :string end end ::Spree::AppConfiguration.prepend(Spree::AppConfigurationDecorator)

It raises error
uninitialized constant Spree::AppConfiguration

Version used: spree 4.5.1, Rails 7.0.4.1